# Bios won't load at all after "your computer ran into a..."

Tags: bios

Yesterday I tried to shut down my computer and while in the process, it showed the blue screen saying "your computer ran into a problem..." then it restarted and I shut it down manually.

Today I tried to turn it on, buy the bios (and subsequently, Windows) won't load at all. No splash screen, nothing. The computer beeps the regular 1 short beep tied to the bios but it just doesn't show anything.

MB: P8H61

Windows 10

I'm currently lost and terrified that I may have bricked it. Thanks for any help.

Edit: After some messing around I suspect it may be the video card as the screen does not show it's not connected, it rather goes into"power saving mode". No clue what to do though.

**Edit:** The main screen was connected to the HDMI and the secondary to the DVI (on the card) with a VGA adapter. Once I removed the adapter and connected the secondary to the on-board VGA, it worked. Then I connected everything the way it always has been and it's working. **Any idea what happened?**

Comment: disconnect the PSU from everything and hook it up to an another computer to see if it even works

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but as I suspected, the PSU is fine. I unplugged the screens and plugged one into the on-board VGA and voilà - windows booted fine. Plugged the main screen into the HDMI port on the video card - and it worked. Any idea what happened?

Comment: Were you using the HDMI port before it stopped working?

Comment: @TheKB Yes, the main one was connected to the HDMI and the secondary to the DVI (on the card) with a VGA adapter. Once I removed the adapter and connected the secondary to the on-board VGA, it worked. Then I connected everything the way it always has been and it's working.

Comment: That's quite odd. Please post if it happens again. If it does, it could indicate that your hardware is faulty.

Comment: @TheKB I agree. Maybe the card is starting to show it's age? (HD7950)

Comment: Perhaps. I have a 7770 in my pc and it's still running fine. Just keep an eye on it.

Comment: So was the adapter the problem?  Is it working now and you no longer need a solution?

Comment: @fixer1234 I can't say that the adapter was the problem, but this just worked. So far all is well.